# I lied in my CV. What is the least horrible way to mitigate the issue?

Tags: resume, applications

I applied to a position and I lied on my CV.

YES I know it is wrong. But this question is not about judging the morals of having lied but the other way around, i.e. how to fix what I have done wrongly. So please do not answer to tell me I did something wrong because I know it already.

The lie is like this: In one of my previous work experiences, I changed the name of the company. Let's say, I was making milkshakes at a hamburgers restaurant, and I changed the name of the company to a pizza company, where I was doing exactly the same milkshakes with the same environment, same conditions etc. Just a different restaurant.

The reason why I did this is because in the application form they were asking how long I was working at a pizza place. But the job is clearly to make milkshakes. So I changed my CV So that I could say I was working 2 years at a pizza place instead of saying 0. Because at that moment, I wrongly judged this could boost my application.

Now they have contacted me and we have an scheduled interview.

What is the least horrible way to fix this issue?
I think when they will ask about my experience at the pizza company I will say it was just 1 day per week and actually I was not very involved in that pizza restaurant, I spent most of my time in a hamburger restaurant. 
Otherwise, if I say upfront I lied, I am totally out of the application process I guess? However, I am out of the game if I do not reveal the lie because if they would hire me, they might find out sooner or later that I was lying.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are a few dozen duplicate questions here. I won't tag this as a duplicate, because looking at a few questions will probably give you better answers than if I were to link 1. You could then delete this question to pre-empt the closing...

Comment: @Mars Fully agree here, this question has been covered in all its variations _a couple of times_ already, I guess self deleting it and doing a proper search on that topic on TWP would be in everyones interest..

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
And let me disagree since there are many questions about lying in CVs, however I can see each question has its own details that make them radically different. So I do not consider it duplicate as just "lying on CV" does not mean the question and answers are the same. As the context of the lying on CV can be extremely different.

Comment: @Worker Then you should edit into your question what you have seen and why you think it's different. As-is, this question will likely be closed as a duplicate

Comment: As far as I can tell, your question is "i lied about how much experience in industry X that I have." You can add "I think experience in industry Y is just as relevant, so I lied and claimed that I have experience in X. What do I do now?"

Comment: Sounds like we really need a cannonical for this type of question which could coalesce the different perspectives. We did similar ones on /travel for common visa refusals.

Comment: Yes. So in my opinion it is radically different to lie in your CV about a) your nationality, b) about the amount of years you worked in a company, c) about what degrees you completed, d)... you name it. It's extremely different.

Comment: @Worker Then explain why it's radically different. You're now attracting downvotes, so apparently other people don't seem to think it's "radically different"... Anyway, I was just trying to help. There are literally dozens of answers with hundreds of upvotes, but if you say they all don't apply to you, then i'm afraid I can't help!

Comment: My assumption is that the requirement to work in a particular industry is to establish domain knowledge relevant for the primary task. In your example, hamburger eaters may prefer different milkshakes than pizza eaters. They may want someone who understands what pizza eaters want.

Answer (score 6):

> if I say upfront I lied...

and

> how to fix what I did wrong

---

Well, you cannot "fix" anything. You can only lower the damage, if you are lucky.

---

*The not-so-good solution*

If you lied only once in the CV, in only one place, you can claim that you made a mistake in the name of the place, unintentionally. While they are likely to not believe, they cannot really prove it either, *if you have a good reason* to explain the mistake. Maybe you had two jobs, maybe there was some celebration at the pizza place just before you updated the CV...

This solution still requires bending the truth, but it is not as blatant as the other one. **You will most likely look (at least) kind of stupid. And you still lie.**

---

*The better solution*

Just admit to the providing the wrong information, wishing to increase your apparent value. Cross fingers and hope for the best. Last minute sincerity might do you some good.

---

*The best solution (not applicable for this job application)*

NEVER ever lie in your CV.

---

*Alternative solution*

**The other way**, which (most likely) will help you **avoid all problems** is to **cancel the application entirely before the interview**. Of course you will not get this job this time at this place, but at least you will not become famous in the area for lying in the CV. You can apply again in a few months, making sure you do not lie.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly. That's why I mentioned the "less horrible" way to handle this. So I am aware I can only lower the damage. 
Other than that the problem is that the name of the company I lied about is exactly in the industry they wanted... to is not like a random change in the name. So it would be spotted as a lie quite quick I believe. I am not sure how to lower the damage

Comment: There is this universal law: to each action there is a reaction. You lied. Something is bound to happen. Luck is a very important factor now.

Comment: True. I think luck plays a huge role right now. Let's see what happens in the interview. I think it might be they do not ask precise questions about a precise position.
But if they ask me precise questions about this position, basically I am screwed up. Saying "Sorry... I must to admit I did not work at that company. I was working at another similar company" would disqualify me...